# Accidentally typed password on logon prompt in Ubuntu TTY, is it stored?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, tty

Note: This is similar, but not identical to the question on how to handle passwords typed into the bash prompt.

On my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, I opened VT1 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and mistakenly typed my password where the username was to be put. I instinctively hit Ctrl+C as when I usually typo my username, which caused the screen to clear and a new prompt to be drawn with the offending "username" no longer shown.

However, do any logs store the attempted username I entered?

I'd rather not grep the logs with the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you enter your password where it ought not to have been entered, a security-concious user ought to change the password.  It would be foolish of me to assure you that it's not been cached somewhere, or to provide any definitive list of places it might be found.

Answer (score 1):

If it is recorded anywhere (which I doubt), it is going to be /var/log/btmp.   Use the lastb command to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at all concerned and have a method to fix this error, fix the error. Asking for advice will not really solve this.

Comment: "However, do any logs store the attempted username I entered?" from original question.

Answer (score 0):

The systemd journal keeps a copy of every login attempt - including failed ones.

a crude fix to delete the offending entries can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272662/how-do-i-clear-journalctl-entries-for-a-specific-unit-only/616732#616732

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).